# Помогите с паралаксом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parallax

Помогите чтоб при скролле до блоков, они выезжали слева/справа и становились на свои места. Но именно чтоб выезжали постепенно во время скролла, а не вылетали анимацией. Надеюсь понимаете о чем я.

https://jsfiddle.net/evhxpawk/7/

```
<div class="content">Контент...</div>
<div class="block1">Блок паралакса, выдвигать слева направо</div>
<div class="block2">Блок паралакса, выдвигать справа налево</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

То что Вы хотите сделать, это не параллакс.

Вот здесь можно почитать -  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81

А вот здесь увидеть воочию, творение разработчика  - http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/

А вот пример "в лоб" того, что Вы хотите сделать. Если Вам не нужно, при прокрутке вверх, чтобы блоки ехали обратно - уберите из кода конструкцию

```
 else {
block1Pos-=10;
block2Pos+=10;
blockFlying[0].style=`left:${block1Pos}%`;
blockFlying[1].style=`left:${block2Pos}%`;
}
```

Пример грубоватый, но суть должен донести.

```js
let wrapContent=document.querySelector('.wrap'),
    blockFlying=document.getElementsByClassName('block'),
    block1Pos=-100,
    block2Pos=100,
    wheel="wheel"||"mousewheel"||"MozMousePixelScroll";
const scrollFly=e=>{
  if ((e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta)>0&&block1Pos<0&&block2Pos>0) {
    block1Pos+=10;
    block2Pos-=10;
    blockFlying[0].style=`left:${block1Pos}%`;
    blockFlying[1].style=`left:${block2Pos}%`;
  } else {
    block1Pos-=10;
    block2Pos+=10;
    blockFlying[0].style=`left:${block1Pos}%`;
    blockFlying[1].style=`left:${block2Pos}%`;
  }
  
};
(wrapContent.addEventListener)?
  wrapContent.addEventListener(wheel, scrollFly):
wrapContent.attachEvent(wheel, scrollFly);
window.onunload=()=>wrapContent.removeEventListener(wheel, scrollFly)||
  wrapContent.detachEvent(wheel, scrollFly);
```

```css
html,body.wrap{width:100%}
body {
  padding-bottom: 500px;
}
.wrap{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.content {
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}
.block{
  position:relative;
  transition:.5s;
}
.block1 {
  background: green;
  left:-100%;
}

.block2 {
  background: yellow;
  left:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">Контент...</div>
  <div class="block block1">Блок, выезжающий слева</div>
  <div class="block block2">Блок, выезжающий справа</div>
</div>
```